# Which architecture, in Python, to use to interact with a third party Web API?

Tags: python, django, api, python-3.x

I am new to web development and working on a personal project with motive to learn to build websites  in Python that interacts with third party API.

My website is very simple, it that allows user to play a YouTube video and list the data corresponding to it, like no. of views, Likes & Dislikes,in the same page similar to a YouTube page where videos are played. I would be using YouTube Data API and Player API to do it.

I would like to know which **web architecture** should i follow to build such a website. I have build sites on MVC architecture in Java but here i am not sure if that is feasible. I would be using urllib2 and requests library to access the API in XML & JSON. I tried to search it in the web but in most of the cases i got 'how to build a Web API' which do not suffice my requirement.

I would appreciate if someone provide me a link to resource or any Github project from where i can learn about architecture in depth.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood your requirements, your app consumes the YouTube API. At the minimum you would need these python packages `flask`, `requests`, `google-api-python-client` and `oauth2client` (documentation available in each project's page)

Here are [some examples from Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python) on how you would use their library.

The [12 factor app](http://12factor.net/) page has general guidlines on how to design a web application.